# Issues with parallelizing the creation of key-value pairs in a Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, multithreading, hash, parallel-processing, jruby

Working with Ruby and wrote the following code using [Parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) and JRuby 1.7.19 to speed up the creation of a hash from an array with many values:

```
hash = {}
array = [
  {"id" => "A001", "value" => 1},
  {"id" => "B002", "value" => 0},
  {"id" => "C003", "value" => 3},
  {"id" => "D004", "value" => 0}]

Parallel.each(array, { in_threads: 5 }) do |item|
  if keep_item?(item)
    hash[item["id"]] = item
  end
end
```

---

```
def keep_item?(item)
  item["value"] > 0
end
```

It was brought to my attention that there could be issues with adding keys to hashes in parallel in Ruby. Is there any risks with this code (thread-safe, loss of data, strange locks I'm unaware of, etc) such that I should have just left it as a regular series `#each` call?

Comment: It will be more clear if you show the code for `keep_item?` and some examples of what the item in `array` looks like.

Comment: I slimmed it down thinking it would be irrelevant. Adding those a couple of those details now.

Comment: IIRC, core classes are not thread-safe. Does adding a mutex solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hash` isn't thread safe. If `keep_item?` visits the `hash`, there will be race condition. Even if it doesn't, there are concurrent updates to the `hash`, which is error prone.

If there's no lock or other synchronization, theoretically there's no guarantee that the updates to a non-thread-safe `hash` on one thread is visible on other thread. The concurrent updates of `hash` without synchronization may lose data, or cause other strange issue. This depends on the implementation of the Ruby `Hash`.

You data is simple enough, just process them using normal `each`. If you use `Parallel`, and add `mutex/lock` for thread safe access, the synchronization overhead will significantly add extra time cost to the overall process. And it's likely the safe parallel version will use more time.

`Parallel` is useful when your task is `IO` bounded, or CPU bounded as long as you have free cores and the task doesn't need to exchange data between each other.

Comment: That sums it up. Unless someone disagrees for any reason, it seems like in this case just letting it run in series is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

While Arie Shaw is correct about Hash not being thread safe I think your implementation is more the issue than anything. If you must process in parallel I would recommend using `Parallel::map` instead e.g.

```
 #lambda just to create the array structure
 lam = ->(n) {n.times.map {|i| {'id' => 'A' + i.to_s, 'value' => [i,0].shuffle.pop }}}
 a = lam.call(40_000)
 require 'parallel'
 Parallel.map(a,in_threads: 5) {|h| [h['id'],h] if h['value'] > 0}.compact.to_h
```

Please Note that this is extraordinarily slower than just running it against the array directly e.g.

```
a.map {|h| [h['id'],h] if h['value'] > 0}.compact.to_h
```

`fruity` results:

```
require 'fruity'
compare do
  in_parallel { Parallel.map(a, in_threads:5){|h| [h["id"],h] if h["value"] > 0}.compact.to_h }
  standard_array { a.map{|h| [h["id"],h] if h["value"] > 0}.compact.to_h }
end

#Running each test 64 times. Test will take about 6 minutes.
# standard_array is faster than in_parallel by 5x ± 1.0
```